# Can I create a Visual Studio WinGDB project for python running on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio, wingdb

I need to develop python code to be run remotely on a Linux machine. I installed an extension to Visual Studio called WinGDB, which is supposed to allow me to use Visual Studio features such as breakpoints and smart editing, while the code exists and runs on the Linux machine. In Visual Studio I created a new project, and in the templates area, chose the template: WinDGB Standard projects -> Multiplatform executable. It created a project for C++.  How do I tell it to instead make a Python project that works remotely with Linux?  Is this even possible?  None of the WinGDB templates mention any particular language. The extent of python support is unclear from the WinGDB documentation (http://www.wingdb.com/docs/pages/wg_intro.htm) and they have not answered my email.  I'm using Visual Studio 2015 update 2, and WinGDB version 4.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I received from WinGDB support:

Unfortunately this is not possible, as WinGDB is meant for native C/C++ development, but not Python.

I think these are different plugins for Python development under VS, or if you do not have to use VS necessarily, you can try this:

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm

This Python IDE supports remote development.